# How exactly did Larry Wu-tai Chin's leak (of a classified document in Oct. 1970) allow China "to reap the maximum political benefits"?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my History Stack Exchange post: [How exactly did Larry Wu-tai Chin's leak (of a classified document in Oct. 1970) allow China "to reap the maximum political benefits"?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/70960/how-exactly-did-larry-wu-tai-chins-leak-of-a-classified-document-in-oct-1970)

Nobody commented, so I have no clue why it got closed? How does it "needs to be more focused" ??  I permit anyone to improve and edit it. Please reopen ?

---

> In the course of his nearly forty-year espionage career, [[Larry Wu-tai] Chin [金无怠]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Wu-tai_Chin) supplied the PRC with information on U.S. intelligence requirements and foreign policy initiatives relating to China, as well as a biographical profile of at least one CIA co-worker, Victoria Loo .<sup>18</sup> In one specific instance he confessed to having passed a classified document to Beijing in October 1970 that discussed President Nixon’s desire to open relations with the PRC.<sup>19</sup> China’s leadership therefore knew about Nixon’s intentions well in advance of his diplomatic overtures. **This would have allowed the country to alter its internal and external policies (such as the volume of anti-U.S. rhetoric in the press) in order to reap the maximum political benefits. [emphasis mine]**
>            As an FBIS analyst and one of the CIA’s few fluent Chinese linguists, Chin was able to pass along such information as Intelligence Information Reports (IIRs) on China and East Asia, biographical profiles and assessments of fellow CIA employees, and the names and identities of the agency’s covert employees. He was also in a position
> to provide information about recruited agents in China.

Nicholas Eftimiades. *Chinese Intelligence Operations* (1994). Page 32.

Kindly expatiate the emboldened quote in Simple English? I am not intelligent, historian, or intelligence officer!

##### How did this foreknowledge "reap the maximum political benefits"? What could China reap solely with, that it couldn't have reaped without, this foreknowledge?

Comment: I would recommend that you take a look at our [tour] page, which describes what this site is about, and perhaps the help page on [ask]. "needs to be more focused" is an indication that you are asking a question/s which requires more of an answer than might be expected from a simple question and answer format.  Whenever we see bullet points that need to be addressed it often indicates that an essay type answer would be required, which doesn't fit our format here. Bullet points are also often part of homework questions, which we also generally consider off topic here.

Comment: @justCal thanks. I edited my post to focus it. what do you reckon of my edit?